# Giving CSS style to a list

Tags: html, css, odoo

I'm working in a personal proyect and I'm learning about CSS. I have created a list using boostrap classes but I need to give a specific CSS style.

This is my actual content:
[image]

And this is the style I need:
[image]

This is the code I'm using on it.

```
<div class="list-group">
 <ul style="padding-left: initial;">
  <t t-if="kids">
   <t t-foreach="kids" t-as="kid">
    <li class="list-group-item">
     <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
      <span class="nav-text">
       <t t-esc="kid.name" />
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
   </t>
  </t>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestion about the CSS?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: try using div layout instead of a list

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [correct html tags](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/). [The documentation of Bootstrap about lists](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/list-group/) is pretty helpfull, though, if you don't know CSS consider taking some time to learn before practicing. :)

You can work from a blank page, and practice there before applying your work to your project.

Have a happy coding time!